# Spring Cloud API Gateway routing not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have designed a micro service prototype using below technologies

1. **Eureka Server**
2. **a service**
3. **Spring Cloud API Gateway**

Above mentioned service are registered in the Eureka Server

[image]

**API Gateway routing Configuration**

```
server.port=8080
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8083/eureka
spring.application.name=ApiGateway
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id=true

spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=service1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://MICROSERVICE1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/service1/**
```

**The service Configuration**

```
server.port=8081
server.address=127.0.0.1
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8083/eureka
spring.application.name=MicroService1
error.whitelabel.enabled= false
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service1")
public class HomeController {
    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String hello() {
        return "response from micro service1";
    }

}
```

When I send a request to the gateway it's showing the below error

```
2020-12-16 22:26:09.770 ERROR 16700 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [d3334561-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/service1/message"

java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'LAPTOP-KU56B6A8' after 3 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1013) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/service1/message" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

How can we solve the above issue?

Comment: Add : eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true  to application.properties file to all your microservices & api-gateway

Comment: In your Service Configuration, you have set the application name as `MicroService1` but have set the id as `service1` in API Gateway Routing Configuration. Also, your uri is set as `MICROSERVICE1`. All 3 different, why?
Put the id and uri to `MicroService1` as the application name is being registered with it only. See if it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have modified the API Gate Way routing Configuration like below

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=service1
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:8081/service1/
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/service1/**
```

Now is working fine

Comment: You simply removed the loadbalancing

Comment: your totally killed the purpose of microservices, by removing load balancing.

Answer (score 7):

Add `eureka.instance.hostname=localhost` in both the microservices instances this will work and not give an error

Comment: Can you explain why this works?  And what was wrong before?

Comment: ran into the same issue, this works like a charm, not sure why though lol maybe API gateway doesn't recognize the localhost until you explicitly specify it ?

Answer (score 3):

Add this bean in your API gateway and you are good to go.

```java
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
}
```

Comment: the above bean should be added to the API gate way and all will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is the only solution works among all of the answers above.

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
}
```

This is the default behavior, so no effect.

```
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
```

This has nothing to do with the discovery client.
It is related with the discovery server.

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

So if you don't know, just don't mess it up with wrong directions.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `pom.xml` file, depending on the version of the dependencies with which the project got initialized there is a slight chance that you have :

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

instead of :

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

notice that in the first it is using **`spring-cloud-starter-gateway-mvc`** instead of the bare **`spring-cloud-starter-gateway`**

correct it and hopefully it might fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Add below to both gateway and individual microservice fix the issue

```
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8010/eureka/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following in `application.yml` file

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: test-service
          uri: lb://MICROSERVICE1
          predicates:
            - Path=/microservice1/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/microservice1/(?<segment>.*), /$\{segment}
```

with this it should works.

Like let say if your microservice1 is url is
`localhost:8081/service1/message`
then you can define the base path of your microservice1 in api-gateway by setting up the path as i did in above configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified my .yaml file with this configuration.
Issue resolved for me.

```
**server:
  port: 9999
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-ws
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
      routes:
      - id: userService
        uri: http://user-service/
        predicates:
        - Path=/user/**
      - id: contactService
        uri: http://contact-service/
        predicates:
        - Path=/contact/**
        
        
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
       defaultZone: http://localhost:8085/eureka**
```

Answer (score 0):

hello jebji if you still have this problem
add
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
in application.properties

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

**Only Add the following property into your API gateway:**

*spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true*

Make sure you already added DevTool maven dependency into your API gateway project but if not then restart it.

Answer (score 0):

add flowing property in application.property file of all eruka client microservice and api gateway , i face same issue and resolve doing same activity

```
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.lower-case-service-id= true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled= true
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

after adding all the above properties then also if you are facing issue then try the below one,

don't use lb://albums_service , but use lb://albums-service .Because URI don‘t support underline.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is "failed to resolve 'LAPTOP-KU56B6A8'".

This is an DNS issue.

- You can set `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true` in the service.

So it will register with its ip at Eureka and the DNS issue can be avoided.

This is actually the same issue as this [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65401512/8574536).

With this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65492040/8574536)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who's coming here and not using Eureka;
In my case I was using Docker and I've specified docker service name instead of localhost in the routes config! (and vice versa). Also putting this here because I am making this mistake twice and if I need to remind myself again :)
(Or maybe we can define this for different environments I guess.)
For example:

```
uri: http://commit-tracker:8081
```

to

```
 uri: http://localhost:8081
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue

I am using

```
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
```

in gateway.

```
springboot version : 3.2.3
```