# Spring Cloud Gateway doesn't work with DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway, eclipse-jee

I was working with Spring cloud gateway when i use routes statique like this (It works fine) :

```
@Bean
RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
    return builder.routes()
            .route((r) -> r.path("/customers/**").uri("http://localhost:8081/"))
            .route((r) -> r.path("/products/**").uri("http://localhost:8082/"))
            .build();
}
```

But when i want to use routes dynamique with DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator doesn't wotk
Here is my function :

```
@Bean
DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator definitionLocator(
        ReactiveDiscoveryClient rdc,
        DiscoveryLocatorProperties properties) {
    return new DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator(rdc, properties);
}
```

And this is my application.properties :

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=gateway-service
spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true
```

when i call this uri http://localhost:8888/PRODUCT-SERVICE/products i get :

```
 Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 22 00:42:19 WEST 2020
[97127699-3] There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

The exception generated in the console :

```
    java.net.UnknownHostException: failed to resolve 'DESKTOP-B8APKA3.mshome.net' after 4 queries 
    at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1013) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/CUSTOMER-SERVICE/customers" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/PRODUCT-SERVICE/products" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1013) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:966) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:414) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.onResponse(DnsResolveContext.java:625) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$400(DnsResolveContext.java:63) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:458) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setSuccess0(DefaultPromise.java:605) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104) [netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.trySuccess(DnsQueryContext.java:201) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.finish(DnsQueryContext.java:193) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolver$DnsResponseHandler.channelRead(DnsNameResolver.java:1230) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) ~[netty-codec-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:93) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.55.Final.jar:4.1.55.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
```

Comment: Have you solved that?

Comment: Yes i did it was a DNS problem so i reset the network parameters and it works.

Comment: yes, for me rebooting PC helped.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was a DNS problem so i reset the network parameters and it works.
If you reset the network and still not work you need to add this propertie :

`eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true`

In all `application.properties` of your services  to register the host's IP address rather than the container's hostname to the Eureka server.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I created this bean and it solved my problem.

```
@Bean
public HttpClient httpClient() {
    return HttpClient.create().resolver(DefaultAddressResolverGroup.INSTANCE);
}
```

Comment: Hello  this answer resolve for me... But i want to know what did it do

Answer (score 3):

Add `spring.cloud.discovery.enabled=true` to `application.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

```
try to add this in all application.properties files.
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
```

`its worked for me`

Answer (score -8):

If there is no problem with the configuration, restart the computer and try.