# Spring cloud gateway api not working even with all right configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, api-gateway

I was trying microservice with eureka discovery server, api gateway and one rest service. Like shown in below image

- [Eureka discovery][1]

**For Service discovery:**

- I have added relevant pom dependencies
- I have added annotations to make spring boot project as discovery service

**application.yml:-**

`server:
  port: 8761
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false`

**For Spring boot service 1:-**

- Added @EnableEurekaClient at main class

**application.yml**

`server:
  port: 9009
spring:
  application:
    name: HEALTH-CARD
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/`

**For Api-Gateway service:-**

- Added @EnableEurekaClient at main class

**application.yml**

`server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
    cloud:
      gateway:
        discovery:
          locator:
            enabled: true
        routes:
          - id: health-card
            uri: http://localhost:9009/health-card
            predicates:
              - Path=/**
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:8761/eureka/`

- Also I have tried with java class route config part

`package com.apigateway.config;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SpringApiGatewayConfig {
    public RouteLocator configRoute(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("healthCard", r->r.path("/health-card/**").uri("localhost:9009/")).build();
    }
}`

Even I have tried all the suggestion from below link
[Spring Cloud API Gateway routing not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65333590/spring-cloud-api-gateway-routing-not-working)
But nothing worked for me. Please help me on this wired case.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGwlB.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try and outdent the spring cloud line in your application yaml

```
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      ...
```

`spring.cloud` is a peer of `spring.application` and your example has it as a child.